# Single row explode with loop

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I have a some data stored in a single column mysql DB that is like this:

```
1-Yizle-smallpic-this is pretty cool-2-User-smallpic-testing!1-Yizle-smallpic-this is pretty cool-2-User-smallpic-testing!-
```

Now I want to output that data in a for loop and need it to loop every 4 hyphens, as the data output would be

```
$uid,$username,$userpicurl,$comment..
```

The code I have so far, obviously works, but only returns the first occurrence.

```
foreach($result->fetch_assoc() as $v){
    list($uid, $username, $userpicurl, $comment) = explode("-", $v); print "$uid $username $userpicurl $comment";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($result->fetch_assoc() as $v) {
    $parts = explode("-", $v);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i+=4) {
        list($uid, $username, $userpicurl, $comment) = array_slice($parts, $i, 4);
        print "$uid $username $userpicurl $comment";
    }
}
```